# How to configure nginx for multi-site reverse proxy?

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to configure nginx as a reverse proxy for two websites on the same server. This is what I'm doing:

```
upstream alpha {     
  server localhost:49212;
}
server {     
  listen 80;
  server_name alpha.example.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://alpha;     
  }   
}
upstream beta {     
  server localhost:49213;
}
server {     
  listen 80;
  server_name beta.example.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://beta;     
  }   
}
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name "";
  return 444;
}
```

It starts and doesn't complain about anything. Then, when I open `alpha.example.com` or `beta.example.com` - I always end up at `http://localhost:49212`. Moreover, no matter what URL I open on port 80, `http://localhost:49212` is rendered.

This is not what I'd expect. I want only `http://alpha.example.com` to be redirected/proxied to `http://localhost:49212` and nothing else. Looks like nginx doesn't pay attention to the `Host` HTTP header and just redirects everything to the first `upstream`.

What is wrong?

Comment: Have you restarted nginx? Check carefully for typos in `server_name`

Comment: Yes, restarted, checked for typos...

Comment: What is serving the sites?

Comment: A few Docker containers with Apache+PHP inside

Comment: I cross-posted this (similar) problem here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/219094/why-nginx-is-not-rejecting-wrong-hosts

Comment: Can you post the apache configs for these two sites?

Comment: How is this related to the problem? HTTP requests must be stopped by Nginx and never reach Apache

Comment: Then your question is not clear because you said the page is rendered just the wrong one. You are also not passing your headers to apache, so by showing your apache config I could see what it is listening for. Try adding  proxy_pass_request_headers on; under proxy_pass.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26399/discussion-between-yegor256-and-drifter104).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here is the answer. The server with an empty `server_name` has to be declared as a "default" one. More details here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name

Nginx, when `Host` HTTP header doesn't match any `server`s, goes into the default one, which is the first, if not specified otherwise. Here is the config that works:

```
upstream alpha {     
  server localhost:49212;
}
server {     
  listen 80;
  server_name alpha.example.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://alpha;     
  }   
}
upstream beta {     
  server localhost:49213;
}
server {     
  listen 80;
  server_name beta.example.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://beta;     
  }   
}
server {
  listen 80 default_server; # pay attention!
  server_name "";
  return 444;
}
```